# Is there a way to test pickers with Robolectric?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I was following the tutorial from Android developer. Right now my class looks like this:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        calendar.set(year, month, day);
        Datable datable = (Datable) view.getContext();
        datable.setDate(calendar.getTime());
    }

}
```

If I try to run a test like the following, I'm getting a NullPointerException on the first `getDataPicker()`. I want to check that the default date is today.

```
@Test
public void testDatePickerFragment() {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int expectedYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int expectedMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int expectedDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();

    FragmentActivity activity = Robolectric
            .buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class).create().start()
            .resume().get();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragment.show(fragmentManager, "datePicker");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    DatePickerDialog dialog = (DatePickerDialog) ShadowDatePickerDialog
            .getLatestDialog();

    assertThat(dialog, is(not(nullValue())));

    assertThat(dialog.getDatePicker().getDayOfMonth(), is(expectedDay));
    assertThat(dialog.getDatePicker().getMonth(), is(expectedMonth));
    assertThat(dialog.getDatePicker().getYear(), is(expectedYear));
}
```

I would like to be able to test this class without using it inside an activity (in that case I believe I can use the `buildActivity` method and then `ShadowDatePickerDialog` but that's the next step).

So, is it possible to test the datePicker? I'm using robolectric 2.2

Comment: I believe this is an issue in Robolectric and is on my to-do list if I can find some time to fix it.

Comment: For the time being, building an activity first is the right solution to solve this nullpointer problem?

Comment: I mean the real activity where I want to embed the datepicker, so starting a FragmentActivity with a layout.

Comment: Any update on this? I've got the same issue using FragmentTestUtil.startFragment. The DatePickerDialog.mDatePicker is still null after construction.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652414/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works with the new version Robolectric 3.X. You can try something like this:

```
    startDate.performClick();
    DatePickerDialog dialog = (DatePickerDialog) ShadowDatePickerDialog.getLatestDialog();
    dialog.updateDate(2013, 10, 23);
    dialog.getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
    assertEquals("2013-11-23", startDate.getText().toString());
```